# Show valid page numbers when the current page number is out of range

Tags: python, django, pagination

Have an issue with the default paginated `ListView` in Django is that when I access a list view with a page number that is out of range, which can typically happen when I refresh the last page while some objects are deleted so the total number of pages is decreased, Django will raise a 404 error.

What I want to do in that case is to show a page with a warning message telling the user the page number is not valid any more, and pagination links which can lead the user the the valid page.

So here is my code

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404

class MyListView(ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return render(request, 'pagenum_out_of_range.html', status=404)

    model = MyModel
    context_object_name = 'my_models'
    template_name = 'my_models_list.html'
    paginate_by = 20
```

and pagenum_out_of_range.html

```html
{% extends my_project_base_template %}

{% block body %}
    <p>Invalid page number and there's no result here. Please try somewhere else.</p>

    {% for object in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ forloop.counter }}">{{ forloop.counter }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't work (no links are shown). I think it's because I didn't pass the context so I changed the last line above to

```py
return render(request, 'pagenum_out_of_range.html', status=404,
              context=self.get_context_data())
```

However the default 404 error comes again.

I'm quite confused about this. What's the correct approach?

---

**UPDATE**

Really appreciate your suggestions and I did more research and debug on this.

I tried overriding some more methods mentioned in [ListView method flowchart](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) to see if I can change the program behavior or grap some intermediate results.

```py
class MyListView(ListView):
    # ...


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print('>>>> get_context_data called')
        r = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print('>>>> get_context_data return:', r)
        return r

    def get_template_names(self):
        print('>>>> get_template_names called')
        r = super().get_template_names()
        print('>>>> get_template_names return:', r)
        return r

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        print('>>>> render_to_response called')
        r = super().render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
        print('>>>> render_to_response return:', r)
        return r
```

When I refresh the page I can see the following output

```
>>>> get_context_data called
>>>> get_context_data called
```

So seems the `get_context_data` is interrupted by some exception and that exception is `Http404` raised from `MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_queryset` as I traced. I guess that's where I should patch.

My concern is I cannot find any official documentation about `paginate_queryset` so I'm not quite sure if that's the proper way.

Comment: try to add the parameter `paginate_by` to the `MyListView` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview `If you’re using pagination, you can adapt the example template from the pagination docs. Change instances of contacts in that example template to page_obj.`

Comment: @BearBrown Thanks for pointing out. Forgot about them when I pasted the code. Updated.

Comment: hmm... may be you need to chage the `status=404` to `status=200` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by overriding the `get_template_names` method. Also, by doing that way I don't think you need to override the `get` method.

```py
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    context_object_name = 'my_models'
    default_template_name = 'my_models_list.html'
    error_template_name = 'pagenum_out_of_range.html'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.status_code == 404:
            return [self.error_template_name]
        else:
            return [self.default_template_name]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However seems `get_template_names` is not called in this case. Updated my post and hope you could take a look.

Comment: The signature of `Paginator.paginate_queryset` is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_queryset  but I really don't think that's where you should touch.